# How to handle Email Opt Out for Various Categories

Tags: email, email-template, apex-email-service, email-alert, massemailmessage

We have a requirement as Contact having 2 checkbox fields as
1. Unsubscribe Newsletter
2. Unsubscribe Webinar Emails
If Contact select "Unsubscribe Newsletter" then no mails will send to the Contact.
As we have only one Salesforce field "Email Opt-out" in Contact for managing email opt-out, how can we achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

I have used the [SFDC Labs Appexchange Package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YDZEA2) with a little customization to handle email opt-out to one of *n* checkboxes managed on the Contact object

The package is essentially an Inbound Apex Email Service and since it can interrogate the incoming message, you can route the unsubscribe request to one or more of the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand the question, but if I do, then you just need a simple workflow field update on Unsubscribe Newsletter that will set the Unsubscribe Webinar Emails checkbox when the first checkbox is checked.

If you have multiple things people can subscribe and un-subscribe to, you may want to consider a child object on Contact where you can manage the various subscriptions. The standard Email Opt Out checkbox is more of a "forget you know me" checkbox whereas the custom checkboxes are more subscription-specific.

Good luck!